# Binding Silverlight ccontrol textbox to a domain context defined as static resource

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I defined a domain context as a user resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:ParkDomainContext x:Key="parkDomainContext" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I have bounded to table query result to  this domain context in my code behind

```
_parkDomainContext = this.Resources["parkDomainContext"] as ParkDomainContext;
_parkDomainContext.Load(_parkDomainContext.GetLocationsQuery(), LoadLocationComplete, null);
_parkDomainContext.Load(_parkDomainContext.GetParksQuery(), LoadParkComplete, null);
```

After this I have bounded the static domain context to a combo box as following

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboLocation" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations, Source={StaticResource parkDomainContext}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Locations, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ParkLocation"
    />
```

It's working fine but when I bind the same domain context to a textbox as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="locationIDTextBox"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"
         Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource parkDomainContext}, Path=Locations.ParkLocation}" >
```

It doesn't show me any result .

I know that my domain context has query result and there must be something wrong in binding it to Textbox.

PLease let me know the solution..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have somewhere a variable holding the current location and bind the textbox to it. Instead, what you have right now is a binding of ComboBox.SelectedItem to the list of locations (which will not work).

Edited after OP comment:
Add to `<UserControl.Resources>`

```
<my:Location x:Key="currentLocation" />
```

Then change the ComboBox to:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource currentLocation}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Then the TextBox:

```
Text={Binding Source={StaticResource currentLocation}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Notes:

1. Please change the type name and
   namespace of Location to your actual
   type
2. This is not really a
   recommended way of doing stuff.
   Usually, you have a class with the
   necessary properties for your XAML
   and set the DataContext of your
   UserControl (or Window) to an
   instance of this class.